# Want to print a message with IDs which is retrieved from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to print a message with Some IDs.. The set IDs are stored in an array..

```
const msg= 'A patient with this Hospital already exsists. Do you want to edit this patient?' + checkAccnt && checkAccnt.map((Pat,i)=><div key={i}><div>{Pat.PatientID}</div></div>);
```

The above I was written. Unfortunetly only the IDs are print as output..THe message that I written infront of it doesn't print..Why?

Comment: why you're assigning to a constant u can just use **<div>your text</div>** or <p>your text</p> map function can be used here too

Comment: I want to print this message as a popup

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you write like this?

```
let msg = 'A patient with this Hospital already exsists.
        Do you want to edit this patient?'
checkAccnt && checkAccnt.map((Pat,i)=>{
  msg += <div key={i}>
    <div>{Pat.PatientID}</div>
 </div>
})
```

Now, to render the msg, use [renderToString](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring):

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

renderToString(msg)
```

Comment: I have a small doubt, If the IDs is more than one the message is also print in that number of times.. I need to print the message at once when multiple IDs occurs..

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Pat.PatientID.join is not a function.. Error occured

Comment: I want to print A patient with this Hospital already exsists.Do you want to edit this patient? + the IDs

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't understand.. How it possible ?

Comment: This only print the count.. I want to print the IDs

Comment: ya.. But The result is, A patient with this Hospital already exsists. Do you want to edit this patient?[object Object][object Object]

Comment: Hit refresh. :)

Answer (score 2):

I got the output

```
let msg2 = 'A patient with this Hospital already exsists. Do you want to edit this patient?';
            let msg1='';
            msg1 = checkAccnt && checkAccnt.map((Pat,i)=>{

                return  <div key={i}>
                          <div>{Pat.PatientID}</div>
                       </div>
              });
              let msg= <div style= {{'fontSize': '16px'}}><div style= {{'fontSize': '16px', 'fontWeight':'bold'}}>{msg2}</div>{msg1}</div>;
```